Put matplotlib style back to default
Since few weeks, I remember installing some extensions and now the background are by default black and the style is weird. Like this :

How can I put the default style back to normal?
I use Jupyter notebooks in visual studio code with the kernel of an Anaconda environment I created called "myenv", and I am on a Windows system if it can help.
Since, then I have to put this line at the beginning of all my scripts, but I would like to avoid to have to do it:
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)

I already tried to change the matplotlibrc file parameters, but didnt work, I tried to uninstall and reinstall, I also tried to execute in ipython some script or some lines to execute at the start of Python, I also tried this with Jupyter directly, but it doesn't work.

Can you verify that when you run matplotlib.matplotlib_fname() the file path does lead to the expected matplotlibrc file that you were changing ?

I used this command to find the matplolibrc to change so yes it is. This morning i tried to uninstall completely anadonca, delete all matplotlib and environments files and reinstall it all and it didn't change anything, meaning that this parameter change comes from outside anaconda and matplotlib files.

Apparently when i do the same thing with jupyter (opened on chrome) but using the same evironment kernel, my plot are fine and print(mpl.rcParams['axes.facecolor']) return "white" as expected instead of "black" when I am on VSCode so the problem must come from VScode
